# Cannot Add Poxy For MSDeploy (Azure Function Deploy)

Tags: visual-studio, azure, proxy, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I want to deploy an azure function app behind a proxy.

The error message is in german but says something like

"proxy authentication required".

It is caused by this in the Output window:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5):

I have already tried these instructions and added the proxy in the devenv.exe.config. (According to the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-network-related-errors-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You followed the instructions at the link you provided, but were you ever prompted to login?

Comment: No I were never prompted

Answer (score 0):

I believe the file you edited was for Visual Studio issues with a proxy. To resolve this issue for MSDeploy, try to add the below config to your `MSDeploy.exe.config` file.

`<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>`